# Animate image from off screen to center of screen

Tags: android, android-animation

I would like to have an (drawable) image start off the screen and animate it to the middle of the screen.

I have searched around a bit and cannot find a great answer.  Some even saying there are problems with starting an animation off the screen.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: what is means off screen ?

Comment: I want the icon to start off of the screen on the left and animate onto the screen moving right until it reaches the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this

```
img.setTranslationX(-screenWidth/2);
img.animate().translationX(0)
             .setDuration(1000)
             .setStartDelay(400);
```